# How can I format user input into a neat table for output in C++

Tags: c++

I am having problems with getting this table to line up correctly, this is a cout statement from my table. My problem is how can I format different things in one line without it messing up the next entry in the line. For example, when I use setprecision(2) for my goldweight, the goldvalue gets messed up and gives me a weird number like 5656e+02

```
 cout << "                   Value Analysis" <<endl;
cout << "Gold: " << setw(6) <<  "" <<goldweight<< "  Oz @ "<<costgold<<"
("<<setw(1)<<    ""<<carats<<"         Carats) $"<<goldvalue<<endl;
```

Comment: Have a look at [`std::iomanip`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/)

Comment: There are apparently errors in your actual formatting of the code sample! Is this your real code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `setw()`, `setprecision()`, etc will mess up stuff.
What you can do is to use temporary `std::ostringstream`.

```
#include <sstream>
...
std::ostringstream oss_goldweight ;
std::ostringstream oss_goldvalue ;
std::ostringstream oss_goldcarats ;

oss_goldweight << setw(6) << goldweight ;
oss_goldvalue << setprecision(2) << goldvalue ;
oss_goldcarats << setw(1) << carats ;
```

and then use oss_goldxyz variables instead of raw values.

Answer (score 0):

you need to reset it for the next input, like if you already set a precision, then you set it back (unset)

```
    std::cout.unsetf ( std::ios::floatfield );
```